# Invoke a ecs task in a private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-nat-gateway

I have a VPC that has one public subnet and one private subnet. There is a Nat Gateway on the public subnet with all the private subnet traffic to it, so I have internet access on the private subnet.

I have an ECS task that has to run in the private subnet(its traffic need to go through the nat gateway as it has the fixed IP that I have to give to the service I am communicating to. The problem that I have is how do I "invoke" or talk to that ecs task from outside as I need to talk to it from outside. I know I could use an ALB but that would be way too expensive for just one task.

I also looked into using an API gateway with a VPC link, but that has to go to an internal load balancer.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you looking to invoke (i.e. start) a task or are you looking to talk to a web server (or similar) running as part of the task?

Comment: Load balancer is your only option.